# Writing a file to protected Sharepoint site using R

Tags: r, sharepoint

I've figured out a way to write a file to a folder located on the hard drive using R. However, now I want to figure out a way to write a file to a protected sharepoint site. Meaning I need to authenticate my username and password before accessing it.

Here is the code I tried using. The thing is it would work and not pass any errors, but the file would not upload.

```
require(gdata)
system("curl --ntml --user Username:password --upload-file C:/Users/Documents/pick.txt https://companyportal.sharepoint.com/file.aspx?file=Shared%20Documents/pick.txt")
plot(dataset);
```

I don't know where it went wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which I managed to solve installing a local sharepoint filesystem on my computer.

Comment: Yeah but I wanted it to work so anyone who puts their username and password would be able to do the same.